# E-mail - регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите хорошее регулярное выражение, которое бы определяло, введен пользователем e-mail или что-то другое.

Также можете советовать функции по проверке e-mail или еще что-то. Делаю упор на безопасности, т.е. на качестве определения e-mail.

Если кроме e-mail еще введено что-то, то оно не должно выполняться.

Comment: Где оно не должно выполняться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])/', $email)
```

(Если парсер чего-то съел, я не виноват)

Comment: Это что? Это дикое извращение с регуляркой. и ты всегда таким пользуешься?

>(Если парсер чего-то съел, я не виноват)

сам писал или взял где-то готовое?

Comment: Не всегда. Но это ещё не самое худшее...

http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: собственно суть не изменилась особо, просто зачем столькамногобукф?

Comment: Не знаю, им виднее. Соответствует RFC, правда не очень хорош тем, что допускает достаточно много вольностей **до** собаки. Хотя всё в пределах стандартов.

Comment: {mail@mail.ru проходит валидацию, хотя в начале стоят фигурные скобки. Не видел в e-mail'ах еще фигурных скобок)

Comment: http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html если искать по этому выражению, то вообще 500 error выдает.

Comment: Там вообще какая-то странная регулярка... Я не смог заставить её работать :-(

А по поводу скобки - вот RFC: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.2.4
[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-] включает в себя достаточно много всяких закорлючек

Comment: да уже хватит спорить бери мой код и смотри, а дальше уже сам прикручивай к нему свои нужные и ненужные символы.

Comment: Решил проблему тем, что удаляю все символы, которые просто не могут быть в e-mail и плюсом простенькая регулярка на e-mail. В итоге навряд ли там сможет выйти что-то похожее на посторонний код.

Comment: но правильный ответ принять нужно.

зачем писать отдельный код и задавать левый вопрос тогда? если нужно решение regexp значит regexp, а не писать что нашел совершенно другое решение-это неправильно. если не получается сделать regexpom значит просто где-то ошибка и её нужно исправить а не искать другое решение.

Answer (score 2):

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Comment: не все перешли еще на 5.3

Comment: пропустил такой вариант: bob}@example.com, остальные не стал проверять, видимо, не доработан еще этот фильтр

Comment: Фильтры появились в PHP 5.2

И потом, это проблема тех кто еще не перешел. Я всего-лишь предложил решение.

Answer (score 1):

```
(^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})
```

взято из этого [cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)

upd: плохая регулярка. не используйте (дорабатываю).

upd: теперь вроде жизнеспособно.

Comment: mail@ma-il.ru попробуйте им проверить... Но вот mail@mail.ru нормально идет.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите [аналогичный вопрос на stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses/201378#201378), там подробно описано.

Напоминаю, что `"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\\ \"weird\".address"@yarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.странныйсайт.рф` — это вполне корректный адрес email. И если бы такой домен был, то на него могла бы прекрасно ходить почта.

Если Вы хотите защититься от какой-либо инъекции (SQL, PHP, HTML, ...) — экранируйте данные, а не проверяйте корректность адреса. Последнее — не поможет.

Comment: это ни разу не корректный адрес.

со слешами, запятыми, кавычками, и уж тем более скобками!

такой адрес не даст создать ни один хостер, да и не один хостер не даст отправить на такой адрес письмо!

Comment: Не врите и не путайте редкость, иррациональность и корректность. Я привет корректный адрес с quoted local part, запятыми, скобками и IDN. То, что такой адрес вряд ли встретится на практике совсем не значит, что он некорректен.

Просто это вычурный случай, специально составленный из того, что может встретиться во вполне нормальном адресе.

Кстати, про «никто не даст отправить»:

    RCPT TO:"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\\\ \"weird\".address"@yarrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.xn--80aa0abrashfei7h.xn--p1ai
    250 2.1.5 Ok
    ...
    250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 2BDC144AA7

Comment: все равно это к вопросу о том что никто себе такой мыльник не сделает.

Представляю себе человека диктующего сей мыльник по телефону.

согласен отправил, но я зарегится на своих сайтах с таким мыльником не дам и это факт, да и многие сайты не дадут, ибо 255 символов дают на почту а тут явно больше, да и на РФ доменах пока что кроме яндекса никто не даёт сделать почту.

**Отправилось письмо, а придет ли и создашь ли ты такой адрес на серваке?** Может он и корректен, но для кого? для системы, а как дже пользователи? так что я все равно при своем мнении останусь.

Answer (score 0):

раз пошла такая тема то.

```
/^[a-zA-Z_\.-][a-zA-Z0-9_\.-\d]*\@[a-zA-Z\.-\d]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/
```

тогда так

Comment: Аналогично с предыдущим. mail@ma-il.ru попробуйте им проверить... Но вот mail@mail.ru нормально идет.

Answer (score 0):

Регулярка + checkdnsrr - не?

Answer (score -2):

```
eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$]"
```

Пользуюсь этой.